# How to add a different item to an array based on the key of an array?

Tags: react-native

I have this array that fetched from backend !
this is the array.

```
resultes
[
[front] [18:52:18]   Object {
[front] [18:52:18]     "cate_id": 1,
[front] [18:52:18]     "name": "Vehicles",
[front] [18:52:18]   },
[front] [18:52:18]   Object {
[front] [18:52:18]     "cate_id": 2,
[front] [18:52:18]     "name": "Home",
[front] [18:52:18]   },
[front] [18:52:18]   Object {
[front] [18:52:18]     "cate_id": 3,
[front] [18:52:18]     "name": "Electronics",
  },]
```

```
 {this.state.categories.results.map((item ,key)=>(
      <View key={key}>

       <Text>{item.name}</Text>
      </View> ))
```

How can add for every item.name a different icon based on the key of the array?
i tried to make an object

```
const CATEGORIES_TYPES = {
      car: {
        style: { width: 50, fontSize: 40, height: 60, color: '#f56217' }
      },
      home: {
        style: { width: 50, fontSize: 40, height: 60, color: '#2c3e50' }
      },
      tv: {

        style: { width: 50, fontSize: 40, height: 60, color: 'black' }
      }
    };
```

and in render:

```
 {this.state.categories.results.map((item ,key)=>(
      <View key={key}>
        {CATEGORIES_TYPES[item.name] && (
        <FontAwesome name={CATEGORIES_TYPES[item.name]} style={CATEGORIES_TYPES[item.name].style} />
      )}
       <Text>{item.name}</Text>
      </View> ))
```

but that don't work Is this a method to add based on the key???

Comment: can you please add what's in `this.state.categories.results`? btw, the `key` used here is just the index of each element in the array, like `0`.. `1`.. `2`..

Comment: I added the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use conditional rendering or have an object with the names of the icons and the name of category as their key.

```
const Icons = {
  Home: 'home',
  Electronics: 'microchip',
  Vehicles: 'car',
};
```

Then in your render do

```
{this.state.categories.results.map((item, key) => (
  <View key={key}>
    {CATEGORIES_TYPES[item.name] && (
      <FontAwesome
        name={Icons[item.name]}
        style={CATEGORIES_TYPES[item.name].style}
      />
    )}
    <Text>{item.name}</Text>
  </View>
))}
```

also change your `CATEGORIES_TYPES` to look like the keys in your categories object.

```
const CATEGORIES_TYPES = {
  Vehicles: {
    style: { width: 50, fontSize: 40, height: 60, color: '#f56217' },
  },
  Home: {
    style: { width: 50, fontSize: 40, height: 60, color: '#2c3e50' },
  },
  Electronics: {
    style: { width: 50, fontSize: 40, height: 60, color: 'black' },
  },
};
```

[DEMO](https://snack.expo.io/@lekgwaraj/fontawesome)

Comment: Good Idea,Thank you

Comment: Thank youuuuu very much

Comment: Excuse me ! How can i make that if i press on any of these categories will navigate to different page ??

Comment: add ```OnPress``` and navigate to your deisred screen.

Comment: I know that  but there is for each of categories a special screen!!!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want to do.

```js
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  car: {
        width: 50, 
        fontSize: 40,
        height: 60, 
        color: '#f56217' 
  },
  home: {
        width: 50, 
        fontSize: 40, 
        height: 60,
         color: '#2c3e50' 
  },
  tv: {
       width: 50, 
       fontSize: 40, 
       height: 60, 
       color: 'black' 
  }
});
{this.state.categories.results.map((item ,key)=>(
      <View key={key}>
   <FontAwesome name={item.name} style={item.name === "car" ? styles.car : item.name === "home" ? styles.home : styles.tv} />
       <Text>{item.name}</Text>
      </View> ))
```

Comment: But i want also the name of the icon to be different like the style

Comment: @amanirose  Like my answer, three different icons are made, and each one has a different style.

Comment: @amanirose  And you try to organize your style in one place like my answer.

Comment: Yes,,like your answer ,,but could we use the key because it is unique

Comment: What is your key? You mean the date_id?

Comment: the key of the results array

Comment: The key can only be unique because it can be distinguished.

Comment: Correct ,,Thank you for your time